Is the time complexity of greedy set cover polynomial or pseudopolynomial?
I have been studying the set cover problem for sometimes and see that its greedy algorithm has a big O complexity of $O(M^2N)$ from this post. However, it seems too good to be true since this is an NP-hard problem similar to the Knapsack problem.
Therefore, my question is "Is the time complexity of greedy set cover polynomial or pseudo polynomial ?"
Would you kindly help me with this ?
Thank you for your enthusiasm !

The greedy set-cover algorithm you mentioned clearly has a polynomial running time. Now you might wonder how come a NP-hard problem has a polynomial time algorithm. The catch is that the greedy set-cover algorithm is not optimal, like most greedy solutions aren't. In fact, we do have a nice approximation bound, namely $O(\log n)$, on the solution quality returned by the greedy algorithm [see wiki] or any standard book.

Why is it not pseudo polynomial ?

Here, the running time is a function of $M$, the number of subsets, and $N$, the number of elements. Both $M$ and $N$ are input sizes and not input values (like profit or weight in the Knapsack problem). Thus, the running time is a simple polynomial (not pseudopolynomial) function in the input size.

It make sense to talk about pseudopolynomial time algorithm only if you get exact optimal solution. For example, in the 0-1 Knapsack problem with dynamic programming, you get pseudopolynomial complexity $O(nW)$, where $W$ depends on the input weights (values, not size) and can be arbitrarily large. If you closely think about it, the value of $W$ can very well be exponential in its size (the number of bits required to encode the weights). Thus, $O(nW)$ is polynomial in input size only for bounded $W$ cases, hence the term pseudopolynomial.

Well it is very convincing but what if I come up with a sub optimal algorithm and somehow it is also pseudopolynomial ? Or does sub optimal algorithm never become pseudo polynomial ?

Of course, it is possible to design an algorithm that is suboptimal and has a pseudo-polynomial running time. But it may not be a very appealing one, because the whole idea of sarcifying a pure polynomial run time is to get an optimal solution. Nevertheless, the appealing factor will depend on the exact problem you are trying to solve.
